# Including PHP variables as hyperlink item

Tags: php, hyperlink

I'm facing problem to create a hyperlink where there are two php variables in the link:

```
       <a href="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/file_uploads/'.$userID.'/'.$Thefile">'.pathinfo($Thefile, PATHINFO_FILENAME) .'</a></td>';
```

It is showing an error.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: What's the error? What are the expected values? That would be helpful to know.

Comment: show us your php code.

Comment: It probably has to do with you not adding $Thefile correctly... `'/'.$Thefile.'">'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given me much to go on.. but try this:

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/file_uploads/'.$userID.'/'.$Thefile.'">'.pathinfo($Thefile, PATHINFO_FILENAME) .'</a></td>';
?>
```

You were missing `.'` just after `$Thefile`.

Answer (score 1):

those quotes can get tricky

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/file_uploads/".$userID."/".$Thefile."\">".pathinfo($Thefile, PATHINFO_FILENAME)."</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know people will get mad at me for not using the proper html quotes but this answer is the prettiest

```
$pathInfo = pathinfo($Thefile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
echo "<a href='http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/file_uploads/$userID/$Thefile'>$pathInfo</a>";
```